# Validation failure when upgrading Keycloak from 19.0.1 to 19.0.2/3

Tags: docker, keycloak, liquibase

I am trying to upgrade my Keycloak docker image version from 19.0.1 to 19.0.2 or 19.0.3 and I get a checksum validation error:

```bash
auth                | 2022-10-31 03:31:50,864 INFO  [io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor] (main) Quarkus augmentation completed in 7220ms
auth                | 2022-10-31 03:31:52,161 INFO  [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.hostname.DefaultHostnameProvider] (main) Hostname settings: Base URL: <unset>, Hostname: <request>, Strict HTTPS: false, Path: <request>, Strict BackChannel: false, Admin URL: <unset>, Admin: <request>, Port: -1, Proxied: false
auth                | 2022-10-31 03:31:53,183 INFO  [org.keycloak.common.crypto.CryptoIntegration] (main) Detected crypto provider: org.keycloak.crypto.def.DefaultCryptoProvider
auth                | 2022-10-31 03:31:54,409 WARN  [org.infinispan.PERSISTENCE] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000554: jboss-marshalling is deprecated and planned for removal
auth                | 2022-10-31 03:31:54,443 WARN  [org.infinispan.CONFIG] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000569: Unable to persist Infinispan internal caches as no global state enabled
auth                | 2022-10-31 03:31:54,463 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000556: Starting user marshaller 'org.infinispan.jboss.marshalling.core.JBossUserMarshaller'
auth                | 2022-10-31 03:31:54,692 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Triskaidekaphobia' 13.0.9.Final
auth                | 2022-10-31 03:31:55,042 INFO  [org.keycloak.connections.infinispan.DefaultInfinispanConnectionProviderFactory] (main) Node name: node_432958, Site name: null
auth                | 2022-10-31 03:31:56,160 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to start server in (development) mode
auth                | 2022-10-31 03:31:56,160 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
auth                |      1 change sets check sum
auth                |           META-INF/jpa-changelog-14.0.0.xml::14.0.0-KEYCLOAK-18286-supported-dbs::keycloak was: 8:c0f6eaac1f3be773ffe54cb5b8482b70 but is now: 8:f43dfba07ba249d5d932dc489fd2b886
auth                | 
auth                | 2022-10-31 03:31:56,161 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Validation Failed:
auth                |      1 change sets check sum
auth                |           META-INF/jpa-changelog-14.0.0.xml::14.0.0-KEYCLOAK-18286-supported-dbs::keycloak was: 8:c0f6eaac1f3be773ffe54cb5b8482b70 but is now: 8:f43dfba07ba249d5d932dc489fd2b886
auth                | 
auth                | 2022-10-31 03:31:56,161 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) For more details run the same command passing the '--verbose' option. Also you can use '--help' to see the details about the usage of the particular command.
auth exited with code 1
```

Is this error standard?

- I have been trying to read the [doc](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/upgrading/index.html#migration-changes), but I couldn't find anything helpful.
- The logs indicate adding the --verbose option, but adding to the image CMD fails. "Option not found".
- My database is fairly simple (I am starting a project). Just 3 realms with 1-2 users and 1 client per realm.

Any suggestions?